# JQuery exclude one field from validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, each

I made this code to validate a checkout form. But there is one field which not need to be required. All the other fields are required. How can I modify my code to exclude this field, and only add the class 'valid' if this field is filled in and not empty.

Has anyone tips for me to do this?

```
// Validate checkout fields
$( '#checkout-data input' ).each( function() {
    $( this ).change( function() {
        if( $( this ).val().length < 1 ) {
            $( this ).removeClass( 'valid' ).addClass( 'invalid' );
        } else {
            $( this ).removeClass( 'invalid' ).addClass( 'valid' );     
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `required` class to the `required input fields` and then change your code like,

```
$( '#checkout-data input.required' ).each( function() {
    $( this ).change( function() {
        if( this.value.length < 1 ) {
            $( this ).removeClass( 'valid' ).addClass( 'invalid' );
        } else {
            $( this ).removeClass( 'invalid' ).addClass( 'valid' );     
        }
    });
});
```

Also, there is no need of `$.each()` like,

```
$('#checkout-data input.required').change( function() {
    if( this.value.length < 1 ) {
        $( this ).removeClass( 'valid' ).addClass( 'invalid' );
    } else {
        $( this ).removeClass( 'invalid' ).addClass( 'valid' );     
    }
});
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/927tQ/)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I do want to add a class 'valid' to this field if it is filled in correctly. How can I do that then?

Comment: You can check it on submitting the form.

Answer (score 0):

Use not() method or :not selector:

```
$( '#checkout-data input' ).not('.exclude')each( function() {
```